# Can somebody explain where the three different Luxembourgs are located?

Tags: europe, terminology, luxembourg

I was putting destination in kayak and came to know that there are three different Luxembourgs. According to kayak it is as below -

1. Luxembourg - This is apparently the country with orage-white-blue shaded flag.
2. Another Luxembourg is Luxembourg, Belgium
3. The last one is Luxembourg, Mosel, Europe.

I am guessing these are 3 different places. I am looking for the one which is supposed to be near Schengen area, where the European agreement was signed. Does anybody have a clue which one is it?

Comment: Greetings from Luxembourg, Belgium! :-)

Comment: That's interesting, but how much research did you do before asking this question? Wikipedia has a [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxembourg_(disambiguation)) listing all the places called Luxembourg and linking to articles with more information about them.

Comment: @Fiksdal is completley wright, I really cannot understand how this question can be rated up.

Comment: I did see that but you are forgetting my friend that I'm not a European but Indian. For me, all I understood is that all three are in Europe and that was confusing enough. I do not know the European map at all and when such choices come when you are trying to book flights, you are stumped.

Comment: I had a suspicion that these three places might be near each other which means three airports and yet it seemed somewhat foolish/fool-hardy to have three international airports so near to each other, hence I needed that clarification to know what is where.  From the below answer it seems all three are and have international airports.

Comment: @Fiksdal and Gnusper hope that clarifies your query.

Comment: Sure, that does clarify how much/little research you did.

Comment: You are right, it seems only one functions - Luxembourg Findel Airport https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxembourg_Findel_Airport . I am curious though then why did kayak.com show the other three when I was doing a 'To' to 'fro' . If there is a single airport, then it should have shown only that one. Confusing again. I don't understand the french names.

Comment: The Mosel is a river that flows through the Grand Duchy of Luxembourg.

Comment: @shirish Yes, "Findel" is the location of the international airport near Luxembourg City (about 15 min by car away, which is why, when you are Luxembourg train station, planes seems to be flying disquietingly low). It's a small airport, actually. If you are coming from outside Europe, you will probably land at Brussels airport, then drive to Luxembourg (2h trip). It is very wrong to say that "all three are and have international airports".

Comment: @shirish *"I did see that but you are forgetting my friend that I'm not a European but Indian"*  I am not understanding how being from India means one couldn't research three different locations on their own, seeing as there are sources of information in almost every language on the ole interwebs.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are a few things called Luxembourg and that might create some confusion:

1. A [small country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxembourg) located at the corner between Belgium, France, and Germany. The color of the flag is more red than orange. It was ruled by the [House of Orange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Orange-Nassau) between 1815 and 1890 and the shape of the flag inspired by that of the Netherlands but I don't think it ever included the color orange, unlike the Dutch flag.
2. The [capital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxembourg_City) of this country, sometimes called “Luxembourg City” or “Luxembourg-Ville” (also the name of the main train station I think).
3. The Belgian [Province de Luxembourg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxembourg_(Belgium)), a region of Belgium located just next to the country named in point 1.

Now, [Schengen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen,_Luxembourg) is a village on the Luxembourgish side of the border tri-point between Luxembourg, France, and Germany. The agreement itself was signed on a riverboat, so as to symbolically be “on the border” without knowing exactly in which country (although for legal purpose, it's considered to be Schengen and Luxembourg is the depositary of the original treaty). The boat, called [“Princesse Marie-Astrid”](http://www.visitluxembourg.com/en/place/lakesrivers/pleasure-boat-ms-princesse-marie-astrid), still does cruises on the Moselle river.

Finally, Schengen is very small, I don't think the area around it was ever known as “Schengen area” in any of the local languages. What's now called “Schengen area” is typically the whole 20+ country strong border-free area.

Comment: And then there’s Luxemburg station which is in Brussels next to the European parliament ;)

Comment: And [Luxemburg, Wisconsin, USA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxemburg_(town),_Wisconsin)

Comment: The flag definitely never included orange. It's "Red, White and Light Blue" (as opposed the the flag of the Netherlands which uses Dark Blue). See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Luxembourg) There is also one with a two-tailed clearly irritated red lion, which some people want to make the new national flag whenever they feel strong for the country or discussion has to be diverted from particularly smelly political crud.

Comment: And yes, the "Schengen area" is set of countries signatory to the [Schengen Agreement](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/index_en.htm)

Comment: Finally there is [Jardin du Luxembourg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jardin_du_Luxembourg), a garden area in Paris, France.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer the Dutch flag did indeed have a top stripe of orange in its original form (the house of, after all), though I do not know if that was ever true of the Luxembourg flag. The flags of New York, and many of its sports teams, inherited this color scheme from the Dutch.

Comment: @phoog No, I have never heard of that. It was Red-White-Blue from the get go.

Comment: @Jan Yes, [Gare de Bruxelles-Luxembourg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brussels-Luxembourg_railway_station) hosts the train line coming in from the east, i.e. from Luxembourg. Nice train ride, but often slower than going by car (unless the Luxembourg-Brussels highway is mercilessly jammed, which happens often).

Comment: @DavidTonhofer both the English and Dutch Wikipedia articles discuss this. The history of the Dutch flag is somewhat more complicated than what I claimed, but its orange-white-blue version was indeed the source of not only the various flags of New York but also of the former flag of South Africa. I've also heard a rumor that Princeton University's orange and black color scheme was originally orange and blue, which makes sense considering that it takes its name from the Prince of Orange. See https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vlag_van_Nederland

Comment: @DavidTonhofer The Luxembourg Gardens are named after the neighboring Palais du Luxembourg and, ultimately the House of Luxembourg and the medieval County of Luxembourg.

Comment: The 'Province de Luxembourg' is also prodomently french speaking, whereas the Grand Duchy of Luxembourg is not. This was on of the reasons for the [Third Partition of Luxembourg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitions_of_Luxembourg#Third_Partition) in 1839.

Comment: @MarkJohnson What do you suppose the Grand Duchy of Luxembourg is? Portuguese speaking? Many Luxembourgish citizens (almost a minority of residents at this point and an even smaller proportion of the working population) will also typically speak Luxembourgish and German but French really dominates nowadays. German was much more important historically but it's a secondary consideration, it was too important strategically for anyone to really care about its populace.

Comment: The Grand Duchy of Luxembourg is a country that lost all of its French-speaking territories in 1839 (65% of it's territory).

Comment: @MarkJohnson Yeah and today French dominates as the language of business, spoken (but not written) in court and the main language all residents have in common (not the first mother tongue, especially for citizens, where it is behind Luxembourgish and Portuguese but definitely the most common). Have you ever been there at all? Read anything about its linguistic situation?

Comment: Yes and?? What has that to do with the reason why the Belgium province was seperated from the Grand Duchy in 1839? Since you also have an account at [History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions), you should not be so **allergic** to any historical explanation as to how the seperation came about and acting as if the situation 184 years ago was the same as today. And yes, as as boy I did a 3 week bicycle tour in April 1970 through both areas so I am familiar with the linguistic situation.

Comment: @MarkJohnson You wrote “The 'Province de Luxembourg' is also prodomently french (sic) speaking, whereas the Grand Duchy of Luxembourg is not“ (present tense). My question to you: What do all your ramblings have to do with this Q&A? You are free to go write on History if you feel like it.

Answer (score 4):

["Luxembourg"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxembourg) refers to various parts of a former medieval Duchy of that name.

The namesake part of the Duchy is a country of that name. To the west is a former part of the country that was occupied by Belgium in 1839, and is the (Belgian) province of Luxembourg.

"Luxembourg" could refer to one (of three) districts in the country that goes by that name.

Finally, it could refer to the capital city (located in the district mentioned above).