# Major international passenger transit hubs near Luxembourg, other than Germany

Tags: air-travel, schengen, luxembourg

This is sort of an extension from my previous [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83693/can-somebody-explain-where-the-three-different-luxembourgs-are-located) . Now I have been trying to locate which international passenger transit hubs near Luxembourg are connected well with BOM and YUL .

The list of countries near Luxembourg are http://www.gomapper.com/travel/list-of-countries-near/luxembourg-0.html

Am looking at the first three (except Germany as have been told they are crazy, specifically Frankfurt) so it's between Belgium, Netherlands and Switzerland.

Also am I correct in my assessment/understanding that I need visa from any one of the these above countries to enter the others (90 day multiple entry visa)?

Comment: [It makes little sense to define a ‘distance’ between Luxemburg, Germany, Belgium and France, since the latter three border Luxemburg (the state).](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/424298019#map=8/49.810/6.147) I think you need to state why ‘Germany is crazy, specifically Frankfurt’, because that looks like it’s tying closest airport with Brussels. Finally, what you heard about visa is correct; the idea of the Schengen area (the group of states) is that there are no border checks between them and people are free to travel between them once they legally entered one.

Comment: My friend lives near Germany and according to him, there visa rules are crazy, hence he has suggested me to try and land one of the other nearby countries which probably doesn't have Frankfurt's strict rules.  I guess that's what he meant.

Comment: Schengen visitor visa rules are pretty much uniform, so if a good flight to Germany pops up in the searches, do consider it.

Comment: If you’re only concerned about visa rules *and* if you’ll be spending most of your time in Luxemburg, you would have to apply for a Schengen visa from Luxemburg anyway, so the visa argument is moot.

Comment: I hope to go to other countries as well. That is why knowing which other countries/airports are good transit hubs would be good to know.

Comment: Your list is a bit odd, why Switzerland and not France? Luxembourg *borders* France and there is a very fast link to Paris. On the other hand, Switzerland isn't that close, certainly by train, are you going to rent a car? I am assuming you wouldn't fly to Luxembourg, otherwise it does not really matter, you could also stop in Rome or something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Now I have been trying to locate which international passenger transit hubs near Luxembourg are connected well with BOM and YUL

Given how far you are coming I would say any major hub in Europe would be within the range of reasonable to consider, personally I would say just put your trip into a planner tool and see what pops up.

I don't think the table of country distances you linked to is helpful, it doesn't say anywhere how it defines the "distance between countries" and many of those countries are much bigger than Luxembourg.

For transit points outside the Schengen area you would obviously need to check visa requirements.

You should probably avoid the UK as afaict (assuming you are Indian) you would need a transit visa to pass through there.

---

> Also am I correct in my assessment/understanding that I need visa from any one of the these above countries to enter the others (90 day multiple entry visa).

For countries in the Schengen area the consulate you are supposed to get your visa from is determined as follows.

1. The country that is the main (i.e. most important) destination of your trip.
2. If there is no main destination then the country you will spend the most time in.
3. If there is no main destination and no country in which you will spend the most time then the country you will enter through.

So if your main destination is Luxemburg then according to the rules you need to get your visa from Luxemburg. Regardless of where you enter the Schengen area and what other Schengen countries you transit through or make side trips to.

Once you have a visa it is formally valid for entering and remaining in all countries in the zone (unless it's a limited territorial validity visa but those are only issued in unusual circumstances).

However lying on a visa application is grounds to annul a visa. Presenting a false itinerary is lying. Remember that suspicion is generally enough for border guards to act, they do not need cast iron proof. Unfortunately some people do lie about their itineraries in order to "consulate shop". Therefore border guards can be suspicious about people entering on a visa issued by another country.

So when you present a visa (especially a single entry visa) at a port of entry in a country other than the one that issued it you should be ready to present evidence (e.g. transportation tickets, accommodation bookings, evidence related to the main purpose of your visit) that you do indeed intend to travel to the country that issued it and that it is either your main or longest duration stay.

Comment: +1, but it's worth spelling out that since you're transiting onwards, you can enter the Schengen area in Germany (Frankfurt) *without* applying via the German embassy.  Luxembourg has an embassy in India.

Comment: It is well possible that your onward travel will be by train, (whatever country you fly to) and buying your train ticket ahead of time and taking that as proof of onward travel is usual and accepted. It does not need to be a flight.